# Wrong Content-Length returned from url when VPN connection is active

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, vpn

I tried to get partial Content-Length from a url that supports ranged request. But it returned full Content-Length like there is no ranged response. I think this is because there is an active desktop FortiClient VPN connection on my machine. When I closed this connection it works well.  How can I fix this problem?

```
var url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip";
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.UserAgent = "C# Application";
req.AddRange(0, 100);
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Content-Length: " + resp.ContentLength);
Console.WriteLine("Accept-Ranges: " + resp.Headers["Accept-Ranges"]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
Content-Length: 20971520
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: 15-20 years ago ISP providers tried to save bandwidth of external internet connection  by routing plain http requests of users  to theirs squid http proxy servers to save frequently requested files locally. Nowadays VPN providers use the same technics to snoop on user traffic to break privacy. You can try https:// request to check such case.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I tried changing the url to `https://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/20MB.zip` but it stucked on getting response. No response received and no exception. Only caused waiting on getting response code line.

Comment: That's probably a problem with the VPN implementation, you should open a support ticket with the vendor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried setting an empty proxy and it worked

```
req.Proxy = new Proxy(); //or
req.Proxy = null;
```

Comment: And does the connection still go through the VPN?

Comment: @Emanuel I think it does. My downloader application is working with chrome extension and gets the headers and cookies using Chrome. I still can download from my business organization websites that need VPN to connect.